# Krita quits on startup, showing "Library key is missing"

Tags: kde, startup

Here is the console log:

```
anforumeru@anforumeru-desktop:~$ krita
Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-n5FBmbq4jQ,guid=45858a1b747e9093d11a267a50aca4c7"
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-n5FBmbq4jQ,guid=45858a1b747e9093d11a267a50aca4c7"
Registered DEC:  true
krita(349)/kdecore (services) KServiceFactory::findServiceByDesktopPath: "kritapart.desktop" not found
krita(349)/kdecore (services) KServiceFactory::findServiceByDesktopPath: "Office/krita.desktop" not found
krita(349)/koffice (lib komain) KoDocumentEntry::createDoc: "The service '/usr/share/applications/kde4/krita.desktop' provides no library or the Library key is missing"
```

I've tried to purge the whole kde dependency tree and install again.
That doesn't help at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile Krita yourself? If so, you probably also need to run kbuildsycoca4 before starting Krita. If that doesn't work, please join us on irc (irc.freenode.net, #krita, http://krita.org/chat is an easy shortcut) or on the forums (http://forums.kde.org/krita) and we'll try to help you out.